# identifier problem with "require"

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) ;
     uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
    uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 
    require (msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require (msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

> ParserError: Expected identifier, got 'LParen'
>           require (msg.value >= min_contribution);

Which identifier should i put after "require"?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are wrong with this function.

1. The signature ends with a `;`, where a `{` should be
2. variables inside functions cannot be public. Public fields should be declared outside the function, for example at the beginning of the contract.
3. If you want to use `msg.value`, you need to declare the function as `payable`

Actually, the lines with `require` are correct for as far as I can tell

End result:

```
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: May be i should put uint256 commands somewhere else, but min_contribution is not working. I`ve sent 0.01 and still got tokens.

Comment: Can you tell me what this function needs to do exactly? For example: what is a contribution in this context?

Comment: I`ve just needed min. contribution size: for example if someone sents less than a 0.1 eth, he get no tokens and recieve ether back.

Comment: There must be something else that is wrong in your situation. This function seems to work like it should for me

Comment: yes, it is working when i am testing it in remix. But after i deploy the contract and send amount of eth that is lower than min_contribution to contract adress, i still recieve tokens

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I was doing a similar process in my presale contract but received a different error. Remix gave an error on last curly bracket saying " ParserError: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected."
Here is the code:

```
    constructor () ERC20("token", "token") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 4000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals())));
}
    address payable public owner;
  
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;

}
```