# Used transfer function for minimal investement - still not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20

```
uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 

function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public payable returns (bool success) {
    require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
    require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
    balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
    balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
    return true;
}
```

So i used this to set the minimal investement, still had no luck, transaction succeed even if i send less than 0.1 ether. Can you guys check what is wrong with it? Also is it possible to set a return if someone sents less than a min.contribution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [identifier problem with "require"](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46542/identifier-problem-with-require)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work just fine. Try this in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract Test {

    uint256 public max_contribution = 50 ether; 
    uint256 public min_contribution = 0.1 ether; 

    function transfer() public payable returns (bool success) {
        require(msg.value >= min_contribution);
        require(msg.value <= max_contribution);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you call the `transfer` function with 1 Ether, it returns `true` and everything works. If you call it with 0 or 60 Ether, the transaction fails and it is reverted.

Comment: it is sooooo weird, because everything works in remix, but when i am deploying it in the testnet, i can do the transactions lower than 0.1

Comment: It's probably not about where you test it but how you test it. My guess is that you are testing it in some wrong way in the testnet.

Comment: maybe... i am not too good at it. I am sending amount of tokens on contract adress from MEW that is lower than min_contribution and still receiving tokens, that`s it...

Comment: `msg.value` is the amount of Ethers, not the amount of tokens. In your question you are asking about restricting amount of Ether. If you mean to restrict the amount of tokens, use `tokens` in your example instead of `msg.value`

Comment: sorry, that was a typo. I am sending ethers, not tokens